# How to authorize into Azure API

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, auth-token

I'm trying to send request into Azure Test API using the personal token I generated at ~/_usersSettings/tokens. I add "Authorization": "Bearer " header to my GET request, but it results in 401 response with an error "TF400813: Resource not available for anonymous access. Client authentication required. - Azure DevOps Server"

How do I do this properly?

Comment: Share your code.

Comment: I don't have any code as of now, I'm trying to make a Post man request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Personal Access Token, it should be basic auth, not bear token auth.

[image]

After that, the request header will be like this:

[image]